# How to display a horizontal table next to a page of text

Tags: tables, graphics, landscape

I'm an entry-level LaTex user. I have a table in landscape orientation that spans a whole page, but as it's not very large, it would be nice to have the text next to it.

Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={16.5cm, 23cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
 
\lipsum[2-8]

\begin{wraptable}{l}{0pt}% automatically uses minimum width
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{1.4\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|llllllll|} 
\hline
Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header  \\ 
\hline
LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex   \\ 
\hline
LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{This is a Caption}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{wraptable}

\end{document}
```

I tried `wraptable`, but it returned errors: `improper \predevdepth. Missing \endgroup inserted. Missing } inserted` at `\begin{landscape}` and `Latex Error: Not in outer par mode. Undefined control sequence. Missing number, treated as 0` at `\begin{table}`.

This is an illustration of what I had in mind:

[image]

Comment: The big problem is if you want to break paragraphs across pages.  flowfram or paracol/afterpage can handle everything except the change in width mid-paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way ... but you have to know where to place the table and what to place next to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={16.5cm, 23cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newsavebox{\testBox}

\begin{document}
 
\lipsum[2-8]

\savebox{\testBox}{\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textheight}
\begin{tabular*}{\textheight}{|l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllllll|} 
\hline
Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header  \\ 
\hline
LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex   \\ 
\hline
LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex   \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\captionof{table}{This is a Caption}
\end{minipage}
}}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\testBox}\vspace{0pt}\usebox{\testBox}\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\testBox-5mm}\vspace{0pt}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An other solution usign tcolorbox package :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={16.5cm, 23cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sidebyside, lefthand ratio=.3,
  sidebyside align=center]
    \rotatebox{90}{
      \begin{tabular}{|llllllll|} 
        \hline
        Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header  \\ 
        \hline
        LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex   \\ 
        \hline
        LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex  & LaTex   \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
    }
    \tcblower
    \lipsum[2-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]